# Выполнение ajax при клике на кнопку

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как сделать выполнение ajax запроса

```
$.get('http://test1.ru/get.php', function(data) {

});
```

при клике на <button>

Answer (score 5):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   $.get('http://test1.ru/get.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Начинайте читать документацию, вопросы примитивные. Хотя бы на русском языке: http://jquery-docs.ru/ (но данные тут старые).

Comment: @Vlmake читайте: http://api.jquery.com/on/

    $('#gp').on('click', ....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
   $.get('http://test1.ru/get.php', function(data) {

   });
});
```

Comment: А можно как то не по button,  а  по id который там ну тоесть id="gp"

Comment: > А можно как то не по button, а по id который там ну тоесть id="gp"

загляните все таки в документацию и справочники, ссылки на которые вам скинули :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('gp').on('click', function() {
   $.get('http://test1.ru/get.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: @danpetruk функция `$()` принимает аргумент как CSS селектор, если он string. Поэтому у вас происходит навешивание событий на элементы с тегом <gp>. Вероятно, не доглядели :)

Answer (score 0):

Код ставь только ПОСЛЕ кнопки к которой привязываешь событие `click` иначе получится так что `JS` обратится к элементу который ещё не подгружен т.е. его ещё нет и ничего не заработает, если надо по `ID` то `$('#myid')`, в общем все как в `CSS`

```
$('button').click(function() {
   $.get('http://test1.ru/get.php', function(data) {
      alert(data);
   });
});
```